# how to remove the "clear sort" state in angular-ui-grid column header?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-ui-grid, tableheader

I see info on adding "disable sort" but not how to remove the default behavior where the 3rd click disables sort and is "neutral" on sortable headers. In reality, having a disable sort state feels broken since it does not actually change the sort order. How do I get rid of the 3rd state and just have it toggle `ASC` and `DESC`?

```
   columns:any[] = [
     { name:'Email', field:'email' },
     { name:'Sessions', field:'sessionCount', enableSorting:false}   //something like enableClearSorting:false
   ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the suppressRemoveSort attribute:

```
columns:any[] = [
     { name:'Email', field:'email' },
     { name:'Sessions', field:'sessionCount', enableSorting:false, suppressRemoveSort: true }
   ]
```

Comment: awesome, I looked all over for this, but wasn't sure what to call the thing I was looking for!